# Tuning mysql, mysqltuner warnings

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm running a Magento website with 100 visitor/hour and have 64GB RAM with an Intel Core i7 CPU. When I run mysqltuner, I receive the message "MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high".

I need help with tuning MySQL to fit my needs, and to clear the warning.

Here is my.cnf file :

```
key_buffer      = 32M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 100
table_open_cache = 4000
table_definition_cache = 8192
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 24
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_io_capacity = 50000
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_commit_concurrency = 8
innodb_old_blocks_time = 1000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G
thread_concurrency = 10
max_connections        = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 18
thread_cache_size = 64
table_cache            = 2000
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size    = 128M
query_cache_limit   = 3M
key_buffer_size = 8G
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 128M
```

What can I do to make the mysqltuner warning disappear?

Comment: 40g for innodb? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size

Comment: Yes, i have read Mysql doc, and it say i can use 80% or my RAM. But when i read the thread you send me, and used sql expression to know how much innodb need i got 2GB. What should i follow Mysql document or the thread?

Comment: All Mysqltuner.pl warnings disappear should NOT be your goal.  If your database size is 5GB, a reasonable innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G*1.4  for ~8G even though you may have a 32GB server.  Overprovisioning sizes can be just as harmful as having insufficient RAM on your server.  Each recommendation has to be carefully considered before taking action.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

Lead with # the following or REMOVE them will allow MySQL defaults
to be used and go a long way toward eliminating the message.

```
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 128M
```

You will find response time is much better.

Please post complete TEXT of MySQL Tuner report.

Additional suggestions Jul 14, 2018

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 24 minimize overhead
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU every second
```

For additional assistance, check my profile, clk Network Profile for contact info. Thanks

Comment: @user3715053 Have you been able to apply any of these suggestions?